# basic dagger java example NPE

Tags: java, dagger-2

I created a simple gradle java project to learn dagger. I have a Bulb which depends on a Button to turn itself on or off. I am trying to print the state of Bulb in my Main class.

Dagger doc states that if we annotate a method with @Inject, then dagger automatically injects that dep when its asked by anyone. In my BulbFactory class, I am trying to inject the Bulb class because I cannot do it directly in Main class as it has static method. 
Please suggest on what I am doing wrong as I get NPE when I try to access methods on the Bulb class.

## Button.java

```
class Button {
    public boolean getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(boolean state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    private boolean state;

    @Inject
    Button() {
    }
}
```

## Bulb.java

```
public class Bulb {

    Button button;
    String color;

    public Bulb(Button button) {
        this.button = button;
    }

    public void turnOn(){
        button.setState(true);
    }

    public void turnOff(){
        button.setState(false);
    }

    public boolean isTurnedOn(){
        return button.getState();
    }


}
```

## BulbFactory.java

```
public class BulbFactory {
    @Inject Bulb bulb;

    public Bulb getBulb() {
        return bulb;
    }
}
```

## Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bulb bulb = new BulbFactory().getBulb();
        bulb.turnOn();
        System.out.println(bulb.isTurnedOn());
    }
}
```

## Build.gradle

```
    plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.shuklz'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.17'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.17'
}
```

https://github.com/theshuklz/learning-dagger

Comment: Don't post a link to your entire project, post the relevant code here as text.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of your setup you're missing an `@Inject` on your `Bulb` constructor.

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Bulb {

    Button button;

    @Inject
    public Bulb(Button button) {
        this.button = button;
    }

}
```

Also, you're not currently using Dagger to inject your dependencies.

You can replace your BulbFactory with a Dagger component which create the `Bulb` class for you. Some more details on components can be found here: https://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.14/dagger/Component.html

In your case you should be able to use something like the following.

```
import dagger.Component;

@Component
interface BulbComponent {
    Bulb getBulb();
}
```

After building the project this will generate `DaggerBulbComponent`. With this you can call `getBulb` to create a new `Bulb` instance.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BulbComponent bulbComponent =  DaggerBulbComponent.builder().build();
        Bulb bulb = bulbComponent.getBulb();
        bulb.turnOn();
        System.out.println(bulb.isTurnedOn());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Chris. I see that the BulbComponent got generated but I am not able to use it in my Main class. 
its generated in build/classes/java/main.
in my build.gradle I have 
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.17'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.17'

Comment: also the generated Bulb_Factory class has 2 static methods, provideInstance() and newBulb() which return me the Bulb instance. I was thinking I can directly use them without creating a component if somehow I can access the generated classpath.